# Relationships in Neo4J

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have two csv files namely: file1.csv {contains fields: Gene, Tumor, Totalpatients, Level} and file2.csv{Gene, Sample, Value, Abundance}

I need to create the relations between two files such as: Gene is connected to Tumor and created to sample too and so on (similar relations)

I am trying the following but it shows me the desired result (explained below the code)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file///home/file1.csv' AS row 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file///home/file2.csv' AS line




MERGE (genes:Genes { name: 'Genes' })
MERGE (cancer:Cancer { name: 'Cancer' })
MERGE (rna:RNA {name: 'RNA'})

MERGE (gene:Gene {name: UPPER(row.Gene)})
MERGE (tumor:Tumor {name: UPPER(row.Tumor)})
MERGE (patient:Patients { name: 'Patients' })
MERGE (total:Totalpatients {name: UPPER(row.Totalpatients)})
MERGE (level:Level {name: UPPER(row.Level)})
MERGE (count:Countpatients {name: UPPER(row.Countpatients)})
MERGE (sample:Sample{name: UPPER(line.Sample)})


MERGE (genes)-[:GENES]->(gene)
MERGE (genes)-[:TUMOR]->(tumor)
MERGE (gene)-[:RNA]->(Sample)


RETURN row;
```

After executing it the relation RNA shows Gene which is connected to empty node i.e no property to show.

How to correct it?

Comment: Can you provide (i.e. gist) the contents of file1.csv and file2.csv?  Or perhaps the first few lines?  Is it correctly creating the :GENES and :TUMOR relationships?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of detailed knowledge of the contents of your .csv files and assuming that the Cypher posted above is exactly the same as that you are executing...

I think this could be a simple casing issue. Spot the difference:

```
MERGE (sample:Sample{name: UPPER(line.Sample)})

MERGE (gene)-[:RNA]->(Sample)
```

You have the identifier `sample` beginning with a lower case 's' but in the relationship `MERGE` statement it is an upper case 'S', i.e. `Sample`.

This could be confirmed by checking whether the node at the other end of the `:RNA` relationship from `gene:Gene` has a label.

```
MATCH (gene:Gene)-[:RNA]-(sample)
RETURN labels(sample)
```

If it does not then the MERGE statement has created the `Sample` node in your original statement as the pattern did not exist. Of course, `Sample` has no labels and no properties - hence your observation.